# Updating array of objects in MongoDb using SailsJS

Tags: mongodb, sails.js, waterline

I have a record in MongoDB in the following format:

```
  {
    attachment: 'xxxxxxx',
    createdAt: TueAug04201514: 52: 23GMT+0400(GST),
    text: 'xxxxxxx',
    sender: '55784247c95c59cc746904e1',
    status: [
      {
        user: '5589464675fc0892757d170e',
        is_read: 0
      },
      {
        user: '55a4a39d5c0bf23d21e6c485',
        is_read: 0
      },
      {
        user: '55a4a38e5c0bf23d21e6c483',
        is_read: 0
      },
      {
        is_read: 0,
        user: '55784247c95c59cc746904e1'
      }
    ],
    thread: '55c0946b80320adb3fd04d0e',
    updatedAt: TueAug04201515: 45: 55GMT+0400(GST),
    id: '55c09967708b73184558fbc8'
  }
```

I would like to update `is_read` inside `status` array. Here is what I have tried.

```
      Messages.update({
          thread: threadIds,
          status: { $elemMatch: { user: user.id, is_read: 0 } }
        },
        { $set: { "status.$.is_read": 1 } })
```

But same query runs really good in mongodb shell. Can anyone guide me if I am missing something? By the way I am running this query in **SailsJS** that uses **Waterline ORM**.

Comment: What kind of relation do you have between the `Message` model and its `status` attribute?

Comment: I couldn't understand what `relation` are you referring. `status` is an attribute of `Message` model with type `array`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is how I solved this.

```
     // You have to use {model_name}.mongo.objectId() for ids otherwise your
     // query will not work.
     threadIds.push(Messages.mongo.objectId(thread.id));

     Messages.native(function (err, collection ) {

        if (err) {
          return res.send(500, err);
        }

        collection.update({
            thread: {$in: threadIds},
            status: {
              $elemMatch: {
                user: user.id,
                is_read: 0
              }
            }
          },
          {
            $set: {"status.$.is_read": 1}
          }, function (err, messages) {

            if (err) {
              return res.send(500, err);
            }

            return res.send(200);

          });

      });
```

Answer (score 3):

To use the "same" query as the mongo shell, you'll have to use [`Model.native`](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/models/native) since Sails is based on Waterline, which has a slightly different query language from Mongo.

I haven't tried this, but I'd wager that this should do it:

```
  Messages.update({
      thread: threadIds,
      'status.user': user.id,
      'status.is_read': 0 
  },
  { 'status.is_read': 1 }, callback);
```

Comment: Yes you are right, I solved this using Model.native but your posted code is wrong.

Comment: I'm glad you did. As I said, I hadn't tried the code. Can you tell me what is wrong so I can update it?

Comment: `'status.user': user: user.id,` here is a syntax error. There can only be one key and its pair.